# Snackbar Pop Up If No Internet Connection

Tags: android, android-studio, android-snackbar

Good day, I'm making an App for educational purposes only. I already enabled Google maps on console developer site.

My questions is, **How do I implement or rather make a condition statement that if GPS not enable in phone / no Internet connection  - is detected the Snackbar will pop up?** - with the text "Some functionalities will be enable/used if connected to the Internet".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check if the device is connected via mobile or wifi you can use this code:

```
ConnectivityManager conMan = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

//mobile
State mobile = conMan.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState();

//wifi
State wifi = conMan.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).getState();
```

and then use it like that:

```
if (mobile == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED || mobile == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING) {
    //mobile
} else if (wifi == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED || wifi == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING) {
    //wifi
}
```

Also to check for GPS status:

```
public boolean isGPSEnabled (Context mContext){
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)
                mContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    return locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
}
```

Comment: I forgot to ask, do you know a github sample for this?

Comment: @RoCk what features exactly do you want?

Answer (score 0):

For checking to network connection, you can make a public function in any file and call it in other files also.

Method look like below :

```
  public static boolean isconnected () {
    ConnectivityManager connMan=(ConnectivityManager) MyApplication.getInstance().getApplicationContext().getSystemServices(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) ;
    NetworkInfo = connMan.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return active != null && active.isConnectedOrConnecting();

     }
```

Here MyApplication is name of activity declared within application tag in manifest file.